# SmackException$NoResponseException thrown when calling XMPPTCPConnection.login (Smack-4.1.0)

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

Environment:

- Server : OpenFire v3.9.3.
- Client OS : Linux
- Server OS : Linux
- Java : 1.8.0_40
- Smack : smack-core-4.10, smack-im-4.1.0, smack-tcp-4.1.0, smack-sasl-provided-4.1.0

Here is my test client code:

```
public class XMPPClientTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setHost("xmpp.domain")
                .setServiceName("xmpp.domain")
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .setResource("Smack-client")
                .build();

        AbstractXMPPConnection conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        try
        {
            System.out.println("connecting");
            conn1.connect();
            System.out.println("connected");

            System.out.println("logging in");
            conn1.login("user", "password");
            System.out.println("logged in");

            ChatManager chatmanager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(conn1);
            Chat newChat = chatmanager.createChat("user@xmpp.domain");

            newChat.sendMessage("Goodbye World!");
            conn1.disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException | SmackException | XMPPException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
connecting
11:49:40 AM SENT (0): <stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' to='xmpp.domain' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>
11:49:40 AM RECV (0): <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client" from="xmpp.domain" id="3d0a3800" xml:lang="en" version="1.0">
11:49:40 AM RECV (0): <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"></starttls><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth"/></stream:features>
logging in
11:49:40 AM SENT (0): <auth xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl' mechanism='DIGEST-MD5'>=</auth>
11:49:40 AM RECV (0): <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09InhtcHAua2lkY2hlY2suY29tIixub25jZT0iYXpqS2N3UUh3S2RjTTVQeWt4OEo2YmdsM1VoMk9JQkVTallBWXFLOSIscW9wPSJhdXRoIixjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04LGFsZ29yaXRobT1tZDUtc2Vzcw==</challenge>
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:250)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnection.java:365)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:452)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:427)
    at com.forge.label.app.driver.test.XMPPClientTest.main(XMPPClientTest.java:39)
Apr 07, 2015 11:49:45 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64.decode(Base64.java:86)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.challengeReceived(SASLMechanism.java:229)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:328)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:313)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1040)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$200(XMPPTCPConnection.java:937)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:952)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I can connect to the server using IM clients like Pidgin. But when I try to use the Smack library I get the above errors. The only "solution" I've found for this problem is to call XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled) but that has not worked in my case.

From the debugging output it appears that the server is sending a challenge and the client is ignoring it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you read and follow the instructions found in https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.1-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide ?

Comment: I did read that and didn't find anything terribly interesting. Though for due-diligence I tried changing my pom to mimic what was represented in the link you sent, and low-and behold it now works.
Thanks for the reply

Comment: Please answer your own question, explain what you did wrong, and mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: @preston.m.price Have you got the solution for this?

Comment: @Flow would you like to answer this question ?

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I removed the dependancy below in my pom.xml

Then, that error didn't show up again.

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
       <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Xmpp connection using smack will be established when you call connect(). But it just initiates the connection process. Connection will be established in background (Separate thread).

In your case you are logging in to xmpp server after the connect() statement. By that time login statement gets executed, connection may not be established. So, use callback methods for connection by implementing the ConnectionListener interface as follows:

```
XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
    connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
        }

        @Override
        public void connected(XMPPConnection arg0) {
            System.out.println("Connected to xmpp service....");
            try {
                connection.login("username", "password");
                System.out.println("Logged in to xmpp service....");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection arg0, boolean arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    connection.connect();
```

Comment: The answer is wrong: `connect()` is a synchronous call.

Comment: Thanks for feedback @Flow . Calling login() followed by connect() should work. Why it is not working?

Comment: I said `connect()` is a synchronous call, you said it's asynchronous (e.g., "…when you call connect(). But it just initiates the connection process. Connection will be established in background .."), and thus you suggest to call `login()` in a connection listener. But this is not required, and therefore the suggestion of this answer is not required..

Comment: But the code i have given in the answer works fine (I am using it in my app ). But calling login() immediately after connect() wasn't worked for me. Could you tell me the reason why it isn't worked?

Comment: No, but I can tell that this can not be the  cause that it's working now. Likely something else has changed while you implement this change

Comment: Thank you @Flow for your feedback. I will try that again.